# External scripts and stylesheets are loaded inline when using a data connection

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3g, content-security-policy

I have detected that if I use a data connection in a mobile phone or I use it as a modem for my computer, the external scripts and stylesheets are not loaded because of my content security policy.

The problem is that all that external files are loaded as inline elements like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" display:"none" >
    // All the file content
</script>
```

The only solution is to admit unsafe inline styles in my policy, but that's not a desired nor valid option.

So, how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using Bundle concepts to load all the external scripts, if any or directly linking the files in the pages?

Comment: No, I use direct links and scripts. If I enter through wifi, several files are requested, but if I enter though a data connection, I get one .html file with the .js and .css embedded.

Comment: Can you try the Bundling of script and load that to the page?